# RotateTransition causing GUI to freeze in javaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, animation, javafx, concurrency

In general, I do not tend to ask for help when it comes to bug fixing, however, I have a very weird one I have spent 2 days trying to fix it without any success. My class is basically a roulette with multiple dificulties so, I used a pieChart to change the dificulties and redraw the roulette fast and with the cool animations that comes with pieChart, however, the method that makes my roulette roll to a certain angle has a big problem, after the RotateTransition ends the GUI freezes complitly. I don´t know why, cause i have other RotateTranstions in other clases and they work fine, also, if i remove the rotateTransition or use other component in it (i tried using images insted of pieChart) it works just fine. I don´t know if pieChart has something special that makes it imposible to use with RotateTransition, also the only exeption to the freeze is the button that allow me to bet again, and yes i already tried "Platform.runLatter()"

```
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        rotateTransition = new RotateTransition();
        rotateTransition.setNode(pieChart);
        rotateTransition.setDuration(Duration.seconds(1));
        rotateTransition.setByAngle(-360);
        rotateTransition.setCycleCount(1);
        rotateTransition.setAutoReverse(false);

        pieChart.setData(dataForX1_5);
        pieChart.setStartAngle(90);
        applyDataWithCustomColor(dataForX1_5, "green", "red");
        
        betButton.setOnAction(eh -> {
            double betMultiplier=1.5;
            if(rbX1_5==group.getSelectedToggle()){
                pieChart.setData(dataForX1_5);
                applyDataWithCustomColor(dataForX1_5, "green", "red");
                betMultiplier=1.5;
            }
            if(rbX2==group.getSelectedToggle()){
                pieChart.setData(dataForX2);
                applyDataWithCustomColor(dataForX2, "green", "red");
                betMultiplier=2;
            }
            if(rbX5==group.getSelectedToggle()){
                pieChart.setData(dataForX5);
                applyDataWithCustomColor(dataForX5, "green", "red");
                betMultiplier=5;
            }
            if(rbX10==group.getSelectedToggle()){
                pieChart.setData(dataForX10);
                applyDataWithCustomColor(dataForX10, "green", "red");
                betMultiplier=10;
            }
            if(rbX25==group.getSelectedToggle()){
                pieChart.setData(dataForX25);
                applyDataWithCustomColor(dataForX25, "green", "red");
                betMultiplier=25;
            }
            if(rbX50==group.getSelectedToggle()){
                pieChart.setData(dataForX50);
                applyDataWithCustomColor(dataForX50, "green", "red");
                betMultiplier=50;
            }
            
            try {
                int betAmount = betAmountSpinner.getValue();
                int spectedResult = (int) (betAmount * betMultiplier);
                if (coins >= betAmount) {
                    dataOutputStream.writeUTF("PlaceBetOnUpgrade");
                    dataOutputStream.writeInt(betAmount);
                    dataOutputStream.writeInt(spectedResult);
                    if (dataInputStream.readBoolean()) {
                        int result = dataInputStream.readInt();
                        int payment = dataInputStream.readInt();
                        coins = coins - betAmount;
                        rotateTo(result, payment);
                        updateCoinsLabel();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    private void rotateTo(int result, int payment) {
        rotateTransition.setToAngle(result * 3.60);
        rotateTransition.setOnFinished(rotateEvent -> {
            if (0 == payment) {
                resultLabel.setText("Lost");
            } else {
                resultLabel.setText("Win");
                coins = coins + payment;
                updateCoinsLabel();
            }
        });
        rotateTransition.play();
    }

    private void updateCoinsLabel() {
        coinsLabel.setText(String.valueOf(coins));
    }
```

Comment: Is all that code necessary to reproduce the problem? Can you condense it down into a [mre]?

Comment: @Slaw I am 100% sure the problem is in the method "rotateTo" if i delete the method or the transition that happen in that method it works, but without animation. I will edit and delete the not necesary part

Comment: read the referenced help page and act accordingly, please

Comment: @kleopatra lol, the question is quite specifical, i literally specified that the problem is inside the rotateTo method whitch has 8 lines of code. Also, the code is to give the contex, and is as easy to replicate like using a RotateTransition with any pieChart.

Comment: and you really expect _me_ (or any other potential helper) to __guess__ the exact code of the complete controller, the fxml, the app and find the bug that's somewhere in _your_ code (that is might be or not in our guessed code)? That will not happen (not from me and probably not from others). BTW: you are aware that notes like _100% sure the problem is in the method_ are logical crap, aren't you? That's correct only if you _know exactly_ what the problem is, in which case asking is ... moot ;)

Comment: Please post something [**reproducible**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), while making an effort to make the example minimal.

Comment: @kleopatra well, as i said all the other parts of the code were checked and worked fine, also i posted the full code but deleted the unecesary parts because someone said it was to much code. To conclude, the problem happens everytime you try to rotate a pieChart no matter what, anyway i found the solution and posted it.

Comment: You were going in the right direction when you made the code more focused. The problem is that your example (both pre and post edit, actually) was never properly reproducible because we couldn't just copy it and execute it. Did the problem turn out to be where you thought it was? Yes. But that only means you were correct in hindsight. When you ask a question here the example should be like you're submitting a bug report. In other words, it should be a [mre]. The linked help page explains what that should look like. Making it easier for us to help you can only mean good things for you.

Comment: Also, the problem you were describing in the question is different than what you describe in your answer. That could just be a language problem though. When you say "freeze" we expect that to mean the application becomes unresponsive. What you're describing is simply that some node overlapped other nodes thus preventing you from interacting with them (_via the mouse_). The application itself, however, was still responsive (i.e. not frozen). In short, your question claimed quite an extraordinary problem that should be impossible, thus a full [mre] was even more important in this case.

Comment: @Slaw Yes, you are right it was not a freeze just and unresponsive GUI, I didn´t realise of that because i had nothing moving in that pane and i couldn´t switch to the others to check cause the buttons were overlaped and imposible to click. Also this is my third language so surely it could has been expresed in a more clear way. I will try to improve my questions in the future, and also edit this one.

Comment: Note if you run into something like this again, try interacting with the controls via the keyboard. If you can then most likely there's a node overlapping them preventing interaction with the mouse. Otherwise if your application truly freezes then typically the operating system will tell you. For instance, Windows will show the spinning circle cursor and tell you the application is "Not Responding".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well i endend up findind the solution to my problem and it was exactly where i said i should be. The problem is that even though you can technically rotate a pieChart using RotateTransition, you have to be aware that when doing it, you are not only rotating the pieChart that you see on the screen but also a transparent layer that is behind it and that even when disable the labels and legends will ocuppy the form of a rectangular with the max posible size. Therefore, when you rotate the pieChart the transparent layer will overlap all your components causing a freeze without any exception. The solution that most would recommend is just to set it as mouse transparent and allow click penetration but, it won´t work, cause it is bugged and will only allow the click penetration in the pieChart but not in the transparent layer, so if you want to rotate a pieChart you need it to be in the center of the screen so even if it roates to a 90º angle it will only overlap the things that are outside of the screen, so it doesn´t matter. if you need to place it elsewhere, you will need to set its max size to something diferent to Max_size and check that it nevers ovelaps anywhing, however, it certainly limits your view quality in high resolutions.

Comment: You may be better of creating your own control using various `Arc` nodes. Assuming you don't really need all the features of `PieChart`.